# Brocade FastIron ignoring ARP cache settings

Tags: arp, brocade

I have a Brocade FastIron FESX648 and I'm attempting to increase the ARP cache timeout on a port that is connected to an IXP. According to the Brocade docs, I can increase the timeout up to 4 hours with the setting `ip arp-age 240`.

I've tried applying this setting globally, specifically to the IXP-facing port and variety of other combinations (lower and higher timeout values), but nothing seems to work. Whenever I run `show arp` I can see that the ARP entries for IXP hosts are continually refreshed and never age higher than 4 minutes.

Has anyone faced a similar problem with Brocade FastIron gear and have any config suggestions or possible workarounds?

Comment: Not sure about Brocade but ARP aging is usually specified in *seconds*, so 14400 might be more what you intended.

Comment: @Zac67 I had that thought too, but the docs specify minutes and if I attempt a value over 240 then it gets rejected by the CLI.